# TypeError: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am new to Angular unit testing (Jasmine karma). I am getting **TypeError: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')** . How to solve it? Thanks in advance.

ts file:

```
export class SelectedComponent extends OnInit {
paidReference: string; 
timeReference: string;
constructor(public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {} 
ngOnInit() { let tempData=
this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams.Ref.split('-');
this.paidReference = tempData[0]; }
} 

spec file: 

describe('SelectedComponent', () => {
let component:SelectedComponent;
let fixture:ComponentFixture<SelectedComponent
    >; beforeEach(async(() => { TestBed.ConfigureTestingModule({
    declarations: [SelectedComponent],
    schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    imports:[modules],
    providers:[{provide: ActivatedRoute, UseValue: {**snapshot: {queryParams:
    {Ref: '123456-15/12/2021'**}}} }]
    }).compileComponents();
    }))

    beforeEach(() => { fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SelectedComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges(); }) 

    it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let tempData= this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams.params.Ref.split('-');
```

Comment: it didnot work. Actually my error is during unit testing- ng test.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `.Ref` to `['Ref']`:

```js
this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams['Ref'].split('-')
```